# Como dar formato numero (con puntos en valores de mil (1.000) a un datatable de jquery

Tags: jquery, datatables

No puedo ordenar una columna numérica, me la ordena pero los puntos los toma como decimales y necesito que el formato sea lo contrario.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias por la ayuda !

Comment: Los valores están guardados en la BD en ese formato? Cuando clickeas para ordernar, se realiza un ajax o el plugin que usas hace el ordenamiento?

Comment: Si es un plug-in, tal vez tenga la opción de especificar miles y decimales, eso ya depende de dicho plug-in y su creador

Answer (score 5):

Tienes que añadir el tipo de la columna cuando defines el DataTable. Eso lo puedes hacer usando el atributo `type` como se explica en [la documentación](https://www.datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/).

Sin ver tu código, no te puedo decir como lo harías, pero aquí te dejo el ejemplo de la página de DataTables:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "columnDefs": [
            { "type": "numeric-comma", targets: 3 }
        ]
    } );
} );
```

Answer (score 1):

O podrías utilizar `http://numeraljs.com/` para darle el formato deseado y que jale los datos como los quieres ordenar.